# Getting API URL from the External File which is not a part of the React app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, continuous-deployment

I have the scenario where I have to the get the API URL from the external file.say config.properties which should not be the part of the build.I am using the webpack for production build.What main intention is to build the react app only once and I need to deploy the resultant build to the multiple environments say example 20 environments.

What I tried is using the webpack DefinePlugin.But for my case, I am able to use this because using like this I have to build for each environment.I am searching for the solution to read the property file from the environment where I will deploy the application.Is there any optimal solution.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('process.env.PROD_123'),
      'API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SinanBolel i edited the question with the snippet which i tried.

Answer (score 0):

In that snippet you are replacing occurrences of `API_URL` with whatever the value of `process.env.API_URL` is at the time of building your bundle.

In order that the application reads the environment variable at runtime, just remove the entry for `API_URL` altogether, so its value will be read at runtime. Note that this will only work within Node, as browser's do not have environment variables.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('process.env.PROD_123')
  }
})
```

If you are in the browser, you can set some value on the global object and pick it up within your bundle like so:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('process.env.PROD_123'),
    'API_URL': 'window.MY_APP.API_URL'
  }
})
```

Whatever other file contains the actual value of `API_URL` should set `window.MY_APP = {API_URL}`.

Comment: Thanks, I understood but my requirement is to read the data from the external file which I will deploy in another path with the production build.Is it possible?We are not using node.

Comment: I would recommend setting a value on some global object (e.g. `window.MY_APP.API_URL`, for example), and accessing it there. I have updated the answer.